# Can not understand why even the 'valid' value is true,everytime run the else statement

Tags: python

```
# Create an @authenticated decorator that only allows the function to run if user1 has 'valid' set to True:

user1 = {
    'name': 'Sorna',
    'valid': True
    }




def authenticated(fn):


    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        if 'valid' in kwargs and kwargs['valid'] is True:

            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print('sorry not valid')

    return wrapper


@authenticated

def message_friends(user):

    print('message has been sent')



message_friends(user1)
```

Comment: Did you try doing `print(kwargs)` in your decorator? You would find that it is empty as you didn't actually pass any key-word arguments. You only passed one positional argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `message_friends` function to accept keyword arguments and then use double stars (**) in front of `user1` dictionary to pass it as keyword arguments.

```
user1 = {
    'name': 'Sorna',
    'valid': True
}


def authenticated(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        if 'valid' in kwargs and kwargs['valid'] is True:

            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print('sorry not valid')

    return wrapper


@authenticated
def message_friends(**kwargs):
    print('message has been sent')


message_friends(**user1)
```